# Windows 98 fails to install with 'Windows Setup requires 7340032 by' error in console

Tags: windows-98

If you install Windows 98 from CD-ROM by first booting from a start-up floppy (such as a Windows 98 Startup Disk) and run `setup.exe`, it will inform the user that it is going to check the hard disks, and then it is possible that you will get a strange, half-formed error message printed into the console like the one below and the installation will halt.

```
Please wait while Setup initializes.
Scanning system registry...
Windows Setup requires 7340032 by
```

The final line may be partially clipped at any point. The full message is

```
Windows Setup requires 7340032 bytes available on your C: drive.
```

This error is somewhat common on a freshly `fdisk`ed hard drive or SD/CF media.

How do you proceed past this error?

Answer (score 27):

This strange error means that hard drive you intend to install Windows 98 onto may be partitioned, but not *formatted* - it appears that Windows' installation system is confused by the lack of a FAT on the destination drive.

Run `format c:` to format the new partition you've established within `fdisk` before running `setup.exe`. (Note that `fdisk` will warn you that you should immediately reboot the system after exiting `fdisk`, before attempting to use the drives you've partitioned.)

If you get the error in the question, follow the following steps:

0. Back up all important data from any drives connected to the system!
1. Boot from the start-up floppy.
2. Run `fdisk` to alter the partitions.
3. Exit `fdisk`.
4. Reboot the computer.
5. Boot from the start-up floppy.
6. You may need to `fdisk /mbr` if this is a completely unused drive, or CF/SD card that's never been used as a bootable drive before.
7. `format` any new volumes you've created.
8. Run Windows 98 `setup.exe`.

Comment: Have you managed to discover the reason the message is clipped?

Comment: I don't have the skills to find out but I'm interested in the answer too.

Comment: So far I have discovered that the issue disappears if setup is launched with the `/nr` option that disables Registry checking.